# MySQL subquery returns more than one row selecting count with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Im executing this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONNECTIONS, SERVERS.NAME AS SERVER_NAME, USERS.USERNAME AS USER, CONECT_DATE AS CONNECTION_DATE
FROM CONECTIONS JOIN SERVERS ON(CONECTIONS.SERVERID = SERVERS.ID)
JOIN USERS ON (CONECTIONS.USERID = USERS.ID)
WHERE CONECTIONS.USERID = (SELECT ID FROM USERS 
WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) =                                 UPPER((SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS)))
AND CONECT_DATE BETWEEN '2010-06-11' AND '2019-06-11' 
GROUP BY SERVERID, CONECT_DATE;
```

Im trying to get this query from each user in the db TABLE USERS with making a subquery to select everyone 'UPPER((SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS)))' and the thing is that is returning more than one row of the result but if I put directly the USERNAME like 'ADMIN' for example it gives me the results.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation? And (aside from all the spelling mistakes) the latter part of this query is gibberish. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
WHERE CONECTIONS.USERID = (SELECT ID
                           FROM USERS 
                           WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) = UPPER((SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS))
                          )
```

This has at least three problems.

1. The subquery argument to `UPPER()` might return more than one value, and likely will, unless the `USERS` table has 0 or 1 rows.
2. The `=` to the `UPPER()` has a similar problem.  An `in` is more appropriate.
3. The use of `=` in the outer `where` clause has a similar problem.  An `in` is more appropriate.

The following fixes these problems:

```
WHERE CONECTIONS.USERID IN (SELECT ID
                            FROM USERS 
                            WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) IN (SELECT UPPER(USERNAME) FROM USERS))
                           )
```

However, I doubt that will fix your overall query.  Your knowledge of SQL seems a bit limited.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you want to do.  That will make it easier for knowledgeable people on this site to point you in the right directions for writing your queries.

Comment: Thanks man! It works prerfectly, I want to display the connections (count the conections) that a each user did to a server in a specific date between date1 and date2.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing `username=select...`. A subquery used in an equality test can return only ONE field/row. Since you're going an unfiltered "gimme everything in the users table", you're returning MANY rows of one field each. For that you need an `IN` match:

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE ... UPPER(username) IN (SELECT USERNAME FROM users)
                         ^^^^---this
```

SQL doesn't permit what is essentially

```
WHERE foo=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

which is why the `IN` operator works, for comparisons of sets of values.

Comment: Well, you could stick with another join